# static_assert depend on class template

Tags: c++, class, c++11, compile-time, static-assert

Consider the following code:

```
template <unsigned int N>
struct myclass
{
    unsigned int f() {return N;}
    unsigned int g() {static_assert(N > 0, ""); return N-1;}
};
```

Question:
Do I have the guarantee that the following code will compile:

```
myclass<0> c;
c.f();
```

But the following will not:

```
myclass<0> c;
c.f();
c.g();
```

Comment: Sure, the first does not instantiate 'g'  (besides, the private nature of the functions)

Comment: @DieterLücking Changed class to struct.

Comment: @Vincent f() should be made public as well as g()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you have that guarantee. From [temp.inst]/11, emphasis mine:

> An implementation **shall not implicitly instantiate** a function template, a variable template, a member template,
>   **a non-virtual member function**, a member class, or a static data member of a class template **that
>   does not require instantiation**.

If you don't call `g()`, it doesn't require instantiation, so there should be no issues calling `myclass<0>{}.f()`.

This is the same guarantee that lets you use `std::vector` and `std::map` with types that aren't default constructible as long as you don't do things like call `resize()` and `operator[]`, respectively.

A followup, as Jarod42 [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788104/static-assert-depend-on-class-template#comment49626487_30788225), is that explicitly instantiating `myclass<0>` will produce the assert because, from [temp.explicit]/8:

> An explicit instantiation that names a class template specialization is also an explicit instantiation of the
>   same kind (declaration or definition) of **each of its members** (not including members inherited from base
>   classes and members that are templates) that has not been previously explicitly specialized in the translation
>   unit containing the explicit instantiation, except as described below.

The exceptions don't apply here.

Comment: Note that explicitly instantiate `myclass<0>` (`template struct myclass<0>;`) will produce the assert.

Comment: Pedantic: "you have that guarantee" modulo the usual disclaimer that the standard only requires a diagnostic message when a static assertion fires and does not require the compilation to fail.

Comment: @Barry: do you have an example of how I can make compilation fails using resize() on a vector for a type that is not default constructible?

Comment: @Vincent Just call `resize(n)` on it for any `n`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a template specialization:

```
template <unsigned N>
struct myclass
{
    unsigned f () { return N; }
    unsigned g () { return N-1; }
};

template <>
struct myclass <0>
{
    unsigned f () { return 0; }
};
```

Comment: This is the right way if you need explicit instantiation, but also a pain because all the other members need to be duplicated.

Comment: @BenVoigt True, but I think in practice, class templates that are designed to enforce constraints do not (and should not) contain much else.

Answer (score -2):

If you wish to disable a function at compiler time, you should use enable_if instead of static_assert

```
template<unsigned int N>
struct Foo {
    unsigned int f() {}
    enable_if_t<(N > 0), unsigned int> g() {}
};

Foo<0> t{};
t.f(); /// this is okay and will compile
// t.g() if I uncomment this line, it will not compile anymore.
```

Comment: Not necessarily.  The usage of enable_if above is incorrect for one thing, as you have to be in a templated context for it to work.  Even turning that into a templated member function, enable_if is really for adding/removing something to the candidate set as opposed to always wanting a hard error when attempting to invoke.

Comment: This will not compile, your enable if isn't in a context in which SFINAE applies, so it's simply a hard failure.